# bootstrap mobile text out of screen

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I was working on a landing page when I try to shrink my page everything works fine beside the header file the text goes off the screen. I wonder if somebody can inlight on this problem.

I haven't use any js code yet.

```css
.stage {
    background: url(img/Header/living-room-1517166_1920.jpg) center center no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    color: white;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<!--Nav bar-->
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-light sticky-top navbar-fixed-top">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Wijkveiligheid</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarText" aria-controls="navbarText" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarText">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Thuis <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Promo video</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Vergelijk</a>
      </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="btn btn_primary" href="#">Login</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
    
<div class="stage" id="stage">
    <div id="stage-caption">
        <h1 class="display-3">Uw veiligheid is onze prioriteit</h1>
        <p class="HeaderP">Wij van wijkveiligheid kijken altijd hoe we het woongenot van onze medemens kunnen verbeteren en optimaliseren. Onze professionele adviseurs staan klaar om samen met u te kijken hoe uw huis ook optimaal beveiligd kan worden en klaar is voor de toekomst.</p>
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Add col and row combination with device screen size classes to fit you content have a look this documentation https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/

Comment: Can you put together a JSfiddle to show whats not working? Since the error is visual it's hard to tell simply from the code.

Comment: Can you also please add bootstrap4 resource and make text visible by changing color: white to something visible

Comment: I uploaded the site to 000webhosting I hope that helps :)

https://wijkveiligheid-demo.000webhostapp.com/

Comment: I fix the problem by adding max width of 500px and then change font-size to 0.9rem.

Answer (score 0):

I fix the problem by adding max width of 500px and then change font-size to 0.9rem.

```css
@media screen and (max-width : 500px) {
    .HeaderP{
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        font-size: 0.9rem;
    }
}
```